# c++ embed python urllib

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7

python 2.7.10(`./Watcher/epMain.py`)：

```
import subprocess
import hashlib
import os
import sys
import zipfile
import httplib
#import urllib 
#import urllib2

def letsbegin():
    subprocess.call('a.exe')
    httpClient = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.google.com', 80, timeout=30)
    httpClient.request('GET', '/updata/Client_V.html')
    response = httpClient.getresponse()
    targetV = response.read()
letsbegin()
```

c++：

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./Watcher')");
PyObject *pyMain = PyImport_ImportModule("epMain")
```

The `pyMain` is always `NULL` but after I change my python code to：

```
 import subprocess
 import hashlib
 import os
 import sys
 import zipfile
 #import httplib
 #import urllib 
 #import urllib2

def letsbegin():
    subprocess.call('a.exe')
    httpClient = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.google.com', 80, timeout=30)
    httpClient.request('GET', '/updata/Client_V.html')
    response = httpClient.getresponse()
    targetV = response.read()
letsbegin()
```

then it is ok to load this module in my c++ code
but I really want to use httplib in this project，How? I can't use:

```
PyImport_ImportModule("httplib")
```

because python code may update often.
besides,when I use

```
d:\pros\go\Watcher>python epMain.py
```

it works!
`urllib` and `urllib2` also have problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you compile with Python 3.x include/libs instead of 2.x.

In Python 3.x, `httplib`, `urllib2` is not available. (They are renamed to `http.client' and`urllib.request`,`urllib.error`)

Change compile option to include, link with Python 2.x.

**UPDATE**

To check which version the C++ program using, try the following code:

```cpp
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.version)");
...
```

Comment: def test():
    return sys.version
c++:
     PyObject* Result = PyObject_CallMethod(pyMain, "test", NULL);
 if(Result)
 {
   char* s = PyString_AsString(Result);
   printf(s);
 }// it returns 2.7.10